# Does the question contain enough information to ask on regular mathematics?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

### Intro

I'm trying to prove that all valid $n^2 \times n^2$ Sudoku solutions follow a cyclic permutation pattern for a subset of $n!$ Sudoku grids.

But, I'm not sure on how to prove it.

$S= {[n....x]}$

Let $n$ be any input length with non-repeating elements.

For $n$ in range shift as follows,

$n$ = 123456789

```
123456789
456789123
789123456
234567891
567891234
891234567
345678912
678912345
912345678
```

Now, suppose I try a different input following the same cyclic pattern

$n$ = 987654321

```
987654321
654321987
321987654
876543219
543219876
219876543
765432198
432198765
198765432
```

for $S = n>> ∞ $,

Given valid solved $n^2 \times n^2$,

$X!$ amount can be generated in $O(n)$ time given any input of non-repeating elements **Do not confuse with O(1) time because the bigger the element the more bits it needs!!! Thus, the more time it takes to execute!**

### Question

I'm not familiar with mathematics, and I'm looking to be pointed in the right direction. How would I prove that this works for ALL $n^2\times n^2$ Sudoku Solutions?

Comment: Are you asking the question in the title, or the question in the body?

Comment: Are you asking if you have a valid solution to a sudoku puzzle then if for example you replace the digits $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ with a permutation of $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)$ that you'll also get a valid solution? I don't really understand what $S$ is and I don't understand the 2 sentences defining $n$ as well. Also in $n^2\times n^2$ the $n$ seems to stand for something else (you probably don't mean $123456789^2\times123456789^2$.).

Comment: A sudoku solution is a form of [latin square](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square), and the mathematical term that is used is [a permutation of symbols](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section04.03.html).  Latin squares are preserved under some additional symmetries that don't preserve the specialized sudoku solutions, but they share equally in preservation by permutation of symbols.

Comment: @hardmath Also, found out I can take any $n^2 x n^2$ general Sudoku Problem and *reduce it into an algorithm in poly-time* that generates that limited $n!$ subset of equivalent instances in $poly-time$. I also found out that solving the correct instances is NP-complete.  In other words, creating an algorithm that generates valid arbitrary Sudoku pre-solved grids is NP-complete. Because, it **first** requires that the general Sudoku be solved!!! By the way the reduction actually works! :)

Comment: @kingW3 I'm defining $n$ as an arbitrary input of 9 elements. Doesn't have to be just 1-9. As long as there is no repeating elements it will generate a valid Sudoku variation in poly-time! And, it will work for any $n^2 x n^2$ solved valid Sudoku puzzle!

Comment: @TravisWells I've thought that was your question? So $n$ is not a number but you seem to use it as such in $n^2 x n^2$,also in your examples did you just switch each instance of 1 with 9,2 with 8,3 with 7, etc.? What exactly do the examples have to do with the question, also for what subset of $n! $ Sudoku grids are you talking about? It could just be me but the whole question seems confusing, and the notation strange.

Comment: @kingW3 I have three links. To explain. 1 ---https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/107183/will-this-algorithm-always-solve-a-constrained-sudoku-puzzle-in-quadratic-time 2 ---https://github.com/tbw1995/Sudoku-Solver-Constrained and 3---https://repl.it/repls/TubbyPrestigiousFirm

Comment: @kingW3 Sorry, to bombard you with reading material. But, I just swapped instances of any elements that follow the same mapping to yield valid $n!$ grids, but only one at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Question here might be considered a discussion of a specific -question, but it is usual to go ahead and ask on the main site, not first ask if one can ask here on meta.

I don't doubt that you have done some research before asking, but it is less of an asking and more of a chatty sharing of ideas.  If you do ask something on the main site, take pains to make clear what the question is.  See [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  Maybe there's a problem to be solved, or a request for help with terminology or references.

But don't use Question posts on the main site to invite open-ended discussion.  That's fine for many sites, but not the kind of content StackExchange tries to collect.